optimum.onnxruntime Yields UnboundLocalError: local variable ‘all_files’ referenced before assignment
Code is below. I have tried numerous popular model names and all give the same error. I used pip install optimum[exporters,onnxruntime]. Both of the below give the same error.
from optimum.exporters.tasks import TasksManager

all_files, _ = TasksManager.get_model_files(‘distilbert-base-uncased’)

and
from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSequenceClassification

model_id = ‘distilbert-base-uncased’
onnx_model = ORTModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_id, export=True)

